# Android and couchbase lite slow in executing liveQuery callback method changed()

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I am trying to develop an Android App with Couchbase. I have a conversations that need to be shown in a Activity. In my onCreate method I call the setUpLiveQuery method. which is as below:

```
    private void setUpLiveQuery() {
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = showLoadingSpinner();


Query query = DBHelper.database.getView("chatDetailsView").createQuery();
query.setStartKey("chat_message_user_" + LoginUserHelper.userdata() + "_user_" + contactNumber + "\u02ad");
query.setEndKey("chat_message_user_" + LoginUserHelper.userdata() + "_user_" + contactNumber);
query.setDescending(true);

Log.v("start of method setupLiveQuery","");

LiveQuery liveQuery = query.toLiveQuery();
this.liveQuery = liveQuery;


liveQuery.addChangeListener(new LiveQuery.ChangeListener() {


    @Override
    public void changed(final LiveQuery.ChangeEvent event) {


         Log.v("Inside method changed","");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

               // Iterating through the data fetched goes here

            }
        });
    }
});
this.liveQuery.start();
```

Now notice the log inside setUpLiveQuery() and changed() When I run, the changed() method is called almost a minute later. Please find the logs below:

12-08 17:28:48.239 1977-1977/com.chromosis.wishhapp.wishhapp V/start of method setupLiveQuery﹕
12-08 17:29:48.871 1977-2005/com.chromosis.wishhapp.wishhapp V/Inside method changed﹕

The execution after that seem faster but the callback to changed() method is taking long time.

Please suggest if I am handling liveQuery appropriately.